# jQuery - cannot extract .data() attribute with calculated key

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working with this jQuery code:

```
$('#selection').bind("change", function(){
     var selected = $(this).find('option:selected');
     var datavar  = selected.text().toLowerCase();
     //alert(datavar);
     //alert('looking for '+datavar+$('#test').data(datavar));    
     //alert($('#test').data('var1'))
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Zwe6h/

The purpose is to choose what data variable you wish to extract from the #test element by using the #selection element. it should alert you as to what the value of that data variable is.

The `datavar` variable is set correctly as `alert(datavar);` prints out the correct value.
However, the second test alert (which is the purpose of this test) displays it as `undefined`. The third test alert simply tests to make sure you can explicitly call the data variables by hard-coding the variable.

I am not understanding why it is coming back with `undefined`. I tested the type of `datavar`, and it is indeed a string, so I would expect it to behave just as it would if it were hardcoded. Can someone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
  alert('looking for  '+datavar + $('#test').data($.trim(datavar)));
```

Issue is with some newline chars (casued by html formatting) in the text selected as they are not included between the option start and end tag. So you just need to trim it.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3vZh7/)**

Or fix your options to include the text in between closing and ending tags.

```
<select name='selection' id='selection'>
    <option value='1'>var1</option>
    <option value='2'>var2</option>
</select>
```

**[Fiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/z7X54/)**

Comment: Thanks very much! Never would have thought of the newline!